# AFNetworking nested param request

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking

I have a rails api that generates locations, and menus for those locations. In my iOS app, I'm using AFNetworking to retrieve a json list of those locations in a table view.

This is the AFNetworking request I use to get Location data

LocationTableViewController.m

```
[[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations.json" parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                                            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                                            NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
                                            for (id locationDictionary in response) {
                                                Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
                                                [results addObject:location];

                                            }
                                            self.results = results;
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        }
                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                        }];
```

A sample of the json returned for the location request

```
 {
    "created_at" = "2013-02-23T19:25:26Z";
    id = 2;
    lat = "48.870175";
    long = "2.779899999999998";
    name = "Disneyland Hotel";
    "places_id" = fd90769e2cf40d6cb6cb1a3d0bfd0ce5d37ed331;
    "street_address" = "Rue de la Marni\U00e8re, Chessy, France";
    "updated_at" = "2013-02-23T19:25:26Z";
},
```

The name and address are displayed

[image]

When a user taps on a location cell, I would like to display a table view of that locations beer list. The rails api route (for location_id => 1) is `http://localhost:3000/locations/1/beers.json` and outputs the following json for a beer that belongs to location_id:1

```
    {
"created_at":"2013-02-23T19:25:53Z",
"description":"fkjgvjkg",
"id":1,"location_id":1,
"name":"nhoihioh",
"price":"2.5","style":"ipa",
"updated_at":"2013-02-23T19:25:53Z"
    }
```

When the user taps a location cell I want to display the beer list for that location, which is consumed via `http://localhost:3000/locations/(whatever location_id is associated with the table cell that was tapped)/beers.json`

How can I insert the location_id into the following AFNetworking request that occurs in the next table view when a user taps a location cell?

BeerTableViewController.m

```
[[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations/**(location_id from location table cell inserted here)**/beers.json" parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                                            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                                            NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
                                            for (id beerDictionary in response) {
                                                Beer *beer = [[Beer alloc] initWithDictionary:beerDictionary];
                                                [results addObject:beer];

                                            }
                                            self.results = results;
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        }
                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Error fetching beers!");
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                        }];
```

I assume I have to log the location_id and pass that value as a param of the url when a table cell is tapped, but am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with JSON you should probably be using AFJSONRequestOperation as it will parse the response data for into a dictionary.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id locationJSON) {

....

};
```

You can then get the places_id from the dictionary and do another call to get the beer info.